# Publish once while using RCL(Razor Class Library)

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I used RCL to store the header and footer of my website and was referenced by several projects.

The projects referenced the RCL by the `Project Reference` of VS.

Every time I modify the RCL, I have to republish all the projects referenced it(By the web deploy). That's so troublesome.

Is there any way that only publishes once while I modify the RCL?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected as the RCL is changed. You may need write some scripts to make it easy to publish the multiple projects after rebuilding the solution.

And you can also use any CI/CD tools for application lifecycle management, for example [Azure DevOps.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/what-is-azure-pipelines?view=azure-devops)

Comment: I want to achieve this for free. I have a strange idea by making a winform program (my server computer is windows server) , checking a directory whether has new rcl file with looping. If it has a new rcl, stop the sites and copy the rcl to all the sites, then restart the sites and delete the file. Can this idea works?